# Quality issue with converting a PNG to PDF with ImageMagick in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick

I have a PNG file with quite decent quality and not at all small size. I convert it to PDF like this(in php):

```
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->readImageBlob($image);
$imagick->setImageFormat('pdf');
echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
```

And I get a PDF file with my image in it. But the quality gets very poor. I thought I might fix with trying different density setting it with `setResolution` method. But this lead to either the image becoming very small or getting even worse quality. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Imagick uses Imagemagick which is not a vector processor. So when convert a raster to a vector, all that will happen is that the raster image will be imbedded in a vector shell. You cannot improve the quality from that of the original raster image. So there is really no point in converting it to PDF. If that does not explain it, then please post links to your PNG and PDF images.

Comment: @fmw42 What I expect is simply a PDF wrapper file with a PNG image put inside as in a container. I expected it to be almost the same quality but instead I get a lot worse quality.

Comment: Please post links to your PNG and PDF images.

Comment: The `echo $image->getImageBlob();` will default to a resolution of 72. How are you implementing `setResolution`?

Comment: @emcconville It's an implemented method in `Imagick` and I believe it's like `denisity` under the hood. `$image->setResolution(300, 300);`

Comment: @fmw42 here are two files: https://yadi.sk/i/vr15ytHx3Yhvru and https://yadi.sk/i/auBucbuM3YhvuZ Pdf is blury but png looks well.

Comment: It is not that blurry. But you can use -unsharp to sharpen it. Try `convert "studio_usage_05_2018 (1).png" -unsharp 0x0.5 result.pdf`. See Imagick unsharpMaskImage() at http://us3.php.net/manual/en/imagick.unsharpmaskimage.php